# PreviewMouseMove vs MouseMove

Tags: c#, xaml, events

I've had my fair share of XAML experience, but recently I noticed that most of my colleagues use **PreviewMouseMove** insead of **MouseMove** event. I've always used **MouseMove** and it has served me well, but I can't help but ask when should I use **PreviewMouseMove** and when **MouseMove**. What's the difference, what pros and cons do each have, etc...?

Comment: Take a look at the [Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PreviewMouseMove is a Tunneling event that is event start from parent container to child and MouseMove is a Bubble event that is it move from child element to parent cotainer. for more detail [see this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140225041901/http://www.csharptutorial.in/2012/10/understanding-event-handling-in-wpf.html)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: New link is not dead : https://web.archive.org/web/20140225041901/http://www.csharptutorial.in/2012/10/understanding-event-handling-in-wpf.html