# Events through user controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have broken my user interface into several user controls and put one inside another. Now I have a structure like this:

```
Main window
    -> top panel
    -> center panel
          -> grid x
          -> command bar
              -> button A
              -> button B...
```

When user press button A, for example, the main window must perform some actions.

How can I implement events in button A that is listened by main window?

Comment: add delegates for that.

Comment: I have to add delegates for every layer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899810/previewmousemove-vs-mousemove/20900593#20900593

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegates for that. Go through following link.

http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2004/10/06/easily-raise-events-from-asp-net-ascx-user-controls/

Comment: I see no way to bubble the event to the main form.